# Using one Java 8 Consumer as Runnable Callback - is threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, thread-safety, java-8

I have a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with 4 active Threads. It gets filled with a bunch of tasks, where each task processes a chunk of items.

Each task must have 3 callbacks: Start, End, and one after each processed item.

Every callback triggers an update in my database. Which is a kinda long running task.

---

Here's a piece of sample code, that should illustrate what I'm doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);

    Consumer<String> processed = (String o) -> {
            System.err.println("PROCESSED: " + o);
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    };

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        executor.schedule(
                new ChunkTask("task"+i, processed),
                500,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

}


public static class ChunkTask implements Runnable {
    String taskId;
    Consumer<String> processedCallback;

    public ChunkTask(String taskId, Consumer<String> processedCallback) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.processedCallback = processedCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            processedCallback.accept(taskId+" "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

I just omitted the start and end callbacks, because it's basically the same as the processed callback.

---

As you can see, I create a single `Consumer` object. Which has a `Thread.sleep(10)` to simulate database access. This object is getting called by all 4 Threads in parallel.

I wonder if this is thread safe. **In my opinion**, the `Consumer` is just a stateless object, with a stateless method. Though it can be called as many times you like in parallel.

Am I right?

---

EDIT: I know that my callback is synchronous. This is just for testing. Later I'd like to make it async.

Comment: Thread-safety is a complex issue.  Suggest you read _Java Concurrency in Practice_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your consumer doesn't have any state, so it's thread-safe. The only shared object it uses is `System.err`, which is itself thread-safe.

Of course, in the real code, the thread-safety will depend on what you do instead of printing to `System.err`. If you use a shared database service and this service is not thread-safe, then you'll have problems.

Comment: Thank you. Of course the Database Access is thread safe. The last question would be: I'd like to schedule new threads from with in the callback. Is that safe?